My program takes too long to start when there is an input needed from the user
I'm using Code::Blocks with the GCC compiler to write C programs as a first-year CS student. I encountered a strange issue when using scanf() in my programs.
The program compiles normally, but when I run it, the terminal window opens immediately and takes about 15 seconds to display any messages or input prompts. However, if I stop the program and re-run it without rebuilding, it starts instantly. The issue reappears if I rebuild the program. When I remove the scanf() calls, the program runs without any delay.
I've tried different approaches but couldn't figure out why this happens. Any insights into what might be causing this delay or how to fix it?
Example of a program:
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int i, x, n;
    int s = 1;
    printf("entrer x \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("entrer n \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        s = s * x;
    }
    printf("%d ^ %d = %d \n", x, n, s);
}


Aside did you mean long int s = 1; ? You use %ld for s in printf().

Compile it with option -Wall and you'll get 2 warnings.

Perhaps your anti-virus is determining if the file is safe. If you disable the anti-virus do you still get that 15-second delay on the 1st run?

Since the very same program starts with different delays, surely it is not the program itself. Instead it is the OS, some anti-malware protection, or the IDE. Start the program outside the IDE and without the anti-malware protection, and [edit] your question to add the results.

I'm afraid that your question is not answerable unless you provide the information requested in the comments above. Please [edit] your question to add this information.

I just don't think this is a program problem. On Windows, calling CRT functions is not efficient, though. The main reason is because of viruses. Your system may take some checking before calling scanf().
My suggestion is to try disable virus checking and so on.
